# pointer adjustment with no multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, static-cast, nullptr

Consider a class layout :

```
| A | B | ( class B is derived from A )
0x0 0x8
```

of course, there is nothing to adjust on downcasting or upcasting.
but is behaviour of compiler defined for this case in Standard.?

if not, then, in general, is static_casting of nullptr safe when there is no multiple inheritance.?

---

```
A * volatile a_ptr = nullptr ; // or change with B * and cast to A * 
assert( ! static_cast< B * >( a_ptr ) ) ; // is that guaranteed by Standard.?
```

Does compiler **always** ( in all implementations ) do not perform adjustment.?

and more generally (for case of multiple inheritance), can compiler adjust nullptr within static_cast.?

---

related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34993934/should-i-expect-that-upcasts-and-downcasts-in-single-inheritance-dont-adjust-th), also unanswered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When does invoking a member function on a null instance result in undefined behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474018/when-does-invoking-a-member-function-on-a-null-instance-result-in-undefined-beha)

Comment: Is what behavior defined by the standard?

Comment: The `static_cast` of a `nullptr` is always undefined behavior in the standard. So no it's definitely not safe.

Comment: @JonathanMee What?  `static_cast` on a `nullptr` is safe.  it gives you a `nullptr` of the type you cast to.

Comment: @NathanOliver Ugh, you're correct, I'm thinking of calling a function on that method. I think you should probably write up that answer.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40031426/2642059). `nullptr` already is a pointer to `NULL` of the type `A` *and* `B`. No need to cast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`static_cast` of `nullptr` is always safe. No matter what is your class layout, you can always `static_cast` nullptr within class hierarchy and will have defined results - `nullptr` of the cast type.

Guarantee that any type cast from `nullptr` will result in `nullptr` can be found in Standard 5.2.9:

> A prvalue of type “pointer to cv1 B,” where B is a class type, can be
>   converted to a prvalue of type “pointerto cv2 D,” where D is a class
>   derived (Clause 10) from B, if a valid standard conversion from
>   “pointer to D” to “pointer to B” exists (4.10), cv2 is the same
>   cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, cv1, and B is
>   neither a virtual base class of D nor a base class of a virtual base
>   class of D. **The null pointer value (4.10) is converted to the null
>   pointer value of the destination type**.

Although `nullptr` can be implictly converted to any pointer type, you might want an explicit cast in some cases, for example, when dealing with templates.

Comment: But then I'm not sure why you'd want to. The `nullptr` is already a pointer to `NULL` matching any type.

Comment: @JonathanMee, for templates, for example.

Comment: @SergeyA, does static_cast check that passed_ptr != nullptr.?

Comment: @GreenTree if the compiler needs to adjust the pointer to account for layout differences I believe it needs to preserve pointers that are `nullptr`, so whatever that takes. In your example though there's no adjustment necessary, so no check is necessary either.

Comment: @Mark Ransom, you are talking about optimizations, but is such check being done in general.?  Please post an answer with quotes from the book.

Comment: @Mark Ransom, if it doesn't burden you.

Comment: @GreenTree the relevant thing is what the standard says. Some people make a habit of reading the standard and others do not - I'm one of those *not* people, but I try to keep myself informed anyway. I'm reasonably certain that the standard says null pointers must be preserved when casting up and down the class hierarchy, but I wouldn't know where to look. Beyond that are implementation details that the standard won't have anything to say about.

Comment: @GreenTree, I've given you guarantees you were looking for.

Comment: @GreenTree, not sure if I understand the question.